# Checking if a variable is a value in a CSV string

Tags: php, regex, csv

Edit: Not looking for anyone to write code for me, just looking for advice on which way is best to achieve what I'm trying to do.

I can think of several ways of doing this, but I was just wondering if there's more elegant ways.

For example, I want to know if "abc" is in "cat,dog,abc,xyz"

These are how I've done it before...

```
in_array($key, explode(',', $value));

(strpos($value, ','.$key) !=== FALSE) || (strpos($value, $key.',') !=== FALSE);

preg_match('/(\,'.$key.'|'.$key.'\,)/', $value) !== 0 // Untested, but.. just for the general idea.
```

Any words of wisdom for better ways, Stack Overflow?

Comment: Provide more information. Your question title seems wrong.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I've edited the title and body of the question a bit. Sorry for the mixup - this started as a totally different question that I answered myself which led to this question, and things got mixed up as I edited the question to ask something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method is probably the most reliable/accurate, and the easiest to read/understand.  However, you should use [str_getcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) instead of `explode()`, because commas could be inside the comma-delimited data.  Example where it breaks down:

```
$key = 'uh, oh';
$value = 'foo,"uh, oh",bar';
```

The other two methods are error-prone and have edge-cases which cause false-positives.  They're very unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

As Jason mentions, your title seems a bit wrong.  But... this is parellel to the examples you've given (5.3+ only):

```
in_array($key, str_getcsv($value));
```

This checks if any column's value in the row `$value` is exactly the value of `$key`